# FFT nightmare )

Tags: c++, fft

I'm using Ooura's FFT to analyse some white noise (duration 75368 smp with 44100 samples of noise). the results i have are quite strange : even with dividing by the number of samples, i have less than 1.0 how is that?

i'm using RDFT and inverse RDFT

actually i have magnitude results like that for example :

```
m1 3.47157
m1 8.50726
m1 29.0233
m1 9.64618
m1 43.2969
m1 60.7396
m1 48.3495
m1 35.8336
m1 32.7611
m1 24.1925
m1 26.8244
m1 17.9448
m1 29.7936
m1 23.1585
m1 15.1243
m1 8.89132
m1 14.6676
m1 18.1515
m1 27.5357
m1 5.6661
m1 19.0589
```

with a FFT size of 4096 and the peak is: 79.119

i was hoping to have results close to one number only (like 1.0 or whatever)

and **if i apply a simple multiplication (like a volume) to the magnitudes, the sound is altered like with a strange filter**...

here are the functions i use to convert from re/im to magnitude/phase:

```
double SuperFFT::_GetPhase(double real, double imaginary)
 {
      return atan2(imaginary, real);
 }

 double SuperFFT::_GetMagnitude(double real, double imaginary)
 {
    return sqrt((real * real) + (imaginary * imaginary));
 }
```

the phase seems good (stays between -PI and PI)

and if i pass a simple sine at 240hz (duration 75368 samples) i have these magnitudes

```
m1 0.262643
m1 0.369384
m1 0.543982
m1 0.851133
m1 1.44518
m1 2.76168
m1 6.37861
m1 21.2081
m1 239.998
m1 775.211
m1 585.819
m1 63.0807
m1 12.06
m1 4.37815
m1 2.07803
m1 1.14897
m1 0.701917
m1 0.460003
m1 0.317885
m1 0.228747
```

this is close to 1 if i divide by the duration and multiply by 100 is it normal?

**why is the sound broken when i multiply the magnitudes** ? Is my FFT broken or am i missing something?

thanks for any help

EDIT : i use OLA of course

Jeff

Comment: "i was hoping to have results close to one number only (like 1.0 or whatever)" I don't understand that. Quick test: apply a constant signal of value 100. What result do you expect and what you get? BTW: I don't know what RDFT means

Comment: RDFT = Real Discrete Fourier Transform. It's a transform where you enter a simple (double* sound) and get the re and im interleaved as a result.

Comment: It's good idea to provide ref links for any term or acronym that is not well known (quick test: google it and see if the wikipedia entry appears in the first 10 items)

Comment: as a result i have random numbers like m1 0.440782
m2 2.8018
m1 0.440362
m2 0.860403
m1 0.440148
m2 -1.08011
m1 0.440288
m2 -3.0217
m1 0.439554
m2 1.31906
m1 0.439157
m2 -0.62069
m1 0.43911
m2 -2.5629
m1 0.438564 (m1 is magnitude m2 is phase)

Comment: Round trip results?  Results for a width 1 signal on the entire round trip?  How about a width 2 signal?  Why start testing with long signals?

Comment: i don't understand your response. do you mean a single DC of value y = 2?

Comment: so i found my error : i was messing with phases in the wrong way. all is well now. thanks to all of you. Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFT implementations typically neglect scaling, allowing some “natural” multiplication of values to occur during the FFT. This is because scaling is often unimportant (e.g., the phase as you have calculated it does not change with scaling, and relationships between certain aspects of the signal do not depend on scale) and because it may be more efficient to adjust the scaling all at one point in the operations instead of in each individual FFT, inverse FFT, and other operations.

You can find the scaling caused by the FFT you are using by setting an input array to 1 in the first element and 0 in all other elements, performing an FFT, and examining the results. Most likely there will be a 1 in the real part of each output element. In this case, the total “energy” of the input is multiplied by N, where N is the number of input elements.

(Since you appear to be doing a real-to-complex transform, there is some subtlety here: N real inputs produces N complex outputs. However, they are symmetrical. For two of them, the element is its own complex conjugate, which compels it to be real. For the remaining N-2, half of them are conjugates of the other half. Because of this, most FFT implementations return you only two real and N/2-1 complex elements. The remaining results are implied: the two missing imaginary components are zero, and the missing N/2-1 complex elements are conjugates of the returned elements. When calculating the total energy of the signal, I mean the energy calculated from all of the N results, not just the ones explicitly returned.)

The maximum possible magnitude any one output element can have is the total energy of all the input. This occurs when the input is a perfect sine wave (with any phase): All its energy is at one frequency, and none is at any other.

Therefore, to calculate the maximum value any output element might have, multiply the maximum energy your input might have by the scaling of your FFT. Then, to normalize the output so that no output exceeds one in magnitude, multiply by the inverse of that product.

Comment: yes but why the sound is broken when i normalize the magnitudes ? If i don't i get a perfect match but with resampling the sound is altered why is that?

Comment: @IonOne: Most likely you have some other bug. In what way are you resampling the sound? Are you playing the result of the FFT, or are you performing an inverse FFT and playing the result of that? What do you do between the FFT and the inverse FFT besides scaling?

Comment: i meant rescaling not resampling sorry....and i play the inverse FFT or course and between the two i do nothing except rescaling. I think i'll try a simple one to one FFT/IFFT and scaling of magnitude to see if there are some other parts of my code that modify the sound you are right

Comment: i did a simple fft/ifft and scaling of the magnitudes and it works perfectly  so it has to come to somewhere else. ***searching -- searching***

Comment: thank you also you did a good answer about rescaling that helped me so i congrat you about pointing me to the right direction- Jeff